# User deleted from User Information List after a change in AD was made

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online

A users password was changed in AD,a user was also removed from the AD group that is connected to a SharePoint group that assigns permissions.

Somehow the users account was deleted from the UserInformationList not long after.. AD Isn't supposed to delete users from this the user information list, does anyone know how this could have happened?

Answer (score 0):

I failed to reproduce your issue. When I changed the password and removed the account from the AD group which is connected to a SP group, the account still exists in the UserInformationList after a few hours. So the steps you mentioned do not necessarily lead to this result. **Please retry with other accounts and share more details.** In theory, even though an account is deleted from AD, it won't disappear from the UserInformationList.

You could use the following cmd in Powershell to fix the wrong data in UserInformationList.

```
$login= "TestUser"
$site= "http://yourdomain.contoso.com"
Set-SPUser -Identity $login -web $site -SyncFromAD
```